# I believe I am getting confused with the pointers in my program

Tags: c

Below I created a function that enters a while loop. In the while loop an if statement is called to traverse the list and check the numbers to see which one is the largest and which one is the smallest. When I run the program only one `printf()` is called, and prints the same `printf()` more than once. It seems to pick two numbers and print them under the same `printf()` function.I know that `firstNumber = firstNumber->next;` is supposed to traverse the list. Isn't `secondNumber = secondNumber->next->next;` supposed to point to the next number in the list?

```
typedef struct A_NewNumber {
    struct A_NewNumber *next;
    double newNum;
} NewNumber;

void NumberSize(NewNumber *start) {

    NewNumber *firstNumber = start;
    NewNumber *secondNumber = start;

    if(start != NULL) {
        while (secondNumber != NULL && secondNumber->next != NULL) {
            secondNumber = secondNumber->next->next;
            firstNumber = firstNumber->next;
            if(secondNumber > firstNumber) {
                printf("The biggest number is:%lf \n",secondNumber->newNum);
            } else {
                printf("The smallest number is:%lf \n",firstNumber->newNum);
            }
            firstNumber = firstNumber->next;
        }
    }
}
```

Example run of complete program:

```
 Please enter a number or
'quit' to stop or 'print' to print/calculate
12
Please enter a number or
'quit' to stop or 'print' to print/calculate
13
Please enter a number or
'quit' to stop or 'print' to print/calculate
14
Please enter a number or
'quit' to stop or 'print' to print/calculate
15
Please enter a number or
'quit' to stop or 'print' to print/calculate
16
Please enter a number or
'quit' to stop or 'print' to print/calculate
17
Please enter a number or
'quit' to stop or 'print' to print/calculate
print
Numbers:12.000000
Numbers:13.000000
Numbers:14.000000
Numbers:15.000000
Numbers:16.000000
Numbers:17.000000

The biggest number is:14.000000
The biggest number is:16.000000
The smallest number is:17.000000
```

Comment: Note that ideally you should provide an MCVE ([MCVE]) that shows how the list is created and supply data, and demonstrate what the MCVE does output and explain what it should output.

Comment: This is your seventh question on the general topic (so far).  Of itself, that isn't automatically bad, but some caution is appropriate.  Does your assignment require you to use a linked list of numbers?  If not, then it would be more sensible to use an array, probably.  Is this code meant to do pairwise comparisons of elements (1,2), (2,3), (3,4), … in the list, or elements (1,2), (3,4), … or something else.  You've not clearly specified this.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I apologize if my lack of knowledge in C  and my lack of knowledge in the use of this site is becoming an issue. When you are asked to do something like this for your first assignment and not very much programming is taught in class. It makes process of doing the assignment a bit uncomfortable. As I keep asking questions, I am learning more about C each time, more than what I get watching countless YouTube videos. Programming as always been hard for me and using this site has made it easier for me to understand. I was able to write a proper function by myself from the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you show what the result is?

I believe that the problem is the assignment of `firstNumber` and `secondNumber`. They do seem to point to the same object. As a consequence, modifying one will modify the other. Moreover, I think it is safe to keep track of the head of the list. I would have done something like this:

```
void NumberSize(NewNumber *start){
   if(start==NULL){
      printf('empty list');
      return;
   }
   double high = start->newNum;
   double small= start->newNum;
   NewNumber *iterator = start->next;

   while(iterator!=NULL){
      if(iterator->newNum > high){
         high = iterator->newNum;
      }
      if(iterator->newNum < small){
         small = iterator->newNum;
      }
      iterator = iterator->next;
   }
   printf("The biggest number is:%lf \n",high);
   printf("The smallest number is:%lf \n",small);
}
```

I m not sure if that's what you wanted to achieve...

Answer (score 2):

Comparison inside `if()` should be on value, not on pointer.

```
if( num1 > num2) {
    // Do something.
} else {
    // Do something else.
}
```

It is because you are executing this `firstNumber = firstNumber->next;` statement twice inside `while()` loop.

```
firstNumber = firstNumber->next;
firstNumber = firstNumber->next;
```

This makes `secondNumber == firstNumber;`